# Standalone helper_method checking for presence, e.g. @user.name if existent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helpermethods

In the view I normally check for presence of a value like this:

```
<%= @user.name if @user.name.present? %>
```

Does it exist something shorter that understands my intention and not needing to repeat what I want to check? I'm looking for something like the following:

```
<%= @user.name if existent? %>
```

If this doesn't exist, would it be possible to construct a helper_method for this (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try @user.try(:name), this wilk return nil if @user is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in more than one place I would probably take @zrl3dx's suggestion and extract that into a helper.

Simply create a ruby file in `app/helpers`, such as `user_helper.rb`

```
module UserHelper
  def current_user
    @user.try(:name)
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can just use:

```
<%= current_user %>
```

That also provides a good way to give a default value. Say you wanted to say "Not logged in" when the user does not exist:

```
module UserHelper
  def current_user
    @user.try(:name) || "Not logged in"
  end
end
```

Of course it would probably be more helpful to give them a link at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I was looking for a more general solution, to validate presence of any instance variable or attribute.

Comment: In that case, have you considered something like a [Null Object](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object)?